# Convert one element from list to int

Tags: python, list, integer, tuples

I'm searching a way to convert only one element from a list that contain a string and a tuple.

My function returns a list that contains a string and a tuple like that : "['X', ([0], [3])]"

```py
def return_case():
  ...
  case = 1
  return [case, coords_case]
```

And the goal is that another fonction takes the case[1][0] as an int.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question?  You want to convert one element.  Which element?    Please clarify with some code as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I modified, and I want to convert the case[1][0] (in this case a 0) to an int

Comment: If you just want to extract the value ```0``` from ```[[0], [3]]``` then @NeffPeff's answer of ```case[1][0][0]``` is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the function take `case[1][0]` and turn it into an int via `case[1][0][0]`

For example:

```
case = ['X', ([25], [3])]
def f(x):
    print(x*x)

f(case[1][0][0])
```

outputs 625

Comment: Oh... I could've just do case[1][0][0] from the beginning, well guess I forgot how python works, thank you